# Completely Remove COM DLL From Registry

Tags: c#, dll, registry

What is the proper way to completely remove COM DLL from the registry?

I'm experimenting with developing a C# COM Dlls. I'm calling them from Excel VBA.  I've developed numerous DLLs (~15) and for the most part have had great success.  When you register a DLL it litters the registry with entries.  I have a very simple DLL with 1 class and 1 interface and it created 15 registry entries (5 for dll, 7 for interface and 3 for class).  I'd like to completely remove the DLLs.  When you use ragasm /u to unregister it only removes the class related entries and leaves the interface and DLL entries.

If I had of been smart I would have created GUIDs with a common first part so it would be easy to write a batch script to remove all experimental DLLs or a particular one.

I've been manually running oleview on the .tlb file to get all the GUIDs and manually searching registry and creating a batch script (.bat) to remove them.  Extremely tedious.  I thought about automating the process.  Before I do that since this has to be a common problem maybe someone has done it or know a good way to do it.

Comment: I understand your desire to be "neat", but don't think it is worth your time to worry about this.  Regsvr32 /u should remove what is necessary so the dll is no longer co-creatable.  Also, it's not a good idea to tweak GUIDs so they "match."  Leave the GUID creation to the tools provided by MSFT.

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy, you should post that as an answer.

Comment: The best way is to have the DLL automatically removed *before* you start building a new version of it.  Project > Properties > Build tab, check the "Register for COM interop" checkbox.  VS must run elevated so it can change the registry.  Cleaning-up afterwards is troublesome since you won't have the correct version of the DLL anymore.  Use /u /tlb to also remove the type library and interface keys.

Comment: It appears using
regasm /u /tlb xxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll
completely removes the dll.

Using
regasm /u xxxxxxxxx.dll 
only removes the class guids and leaves the dll guids and interface guids.  This isn't documented or I couldn't find it mentioned.